# Why was Shaul punished for not killing the Amaleiki animals?

Tags: samuel-shmuel-book-of, king-saul

Shaul was commanded to kill the Amaleki animals, which he did not do, and lost his kingdom as a result. ([Shmuel 1 15](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15844/jewish/Chapter-15.htm))

But he was planning on offering them as sacrifices. What would be the end of the world if he would kill them by offering them rather than just throwing them out?

Comment: As I recall, they were to be killed at once and there was an isur hana'ah (forbidden to derive benefit) on the animals. Bringing them as sacrifices would have enabled them to eat the animals and would violate the specific command. Since Hashem commanded that they not be brought as sacrifices, offering them would have been an insult to Hashem.

Comment: Some sacrifices are eaten at least in part. Why do you assume they didn't intent to eat them?

Comment: I'm afraid this question could be answered from a peshat level, as @mevaqesh pointed out.

Comment: @mevaqesh why do you assume that they _did_ intend to eat of the sacrifice? Perhaps they were going to offer Olahs?

Comment: @mevaqesh, perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question? I don't see any assumption the proposed offerings would not be eaten.

Comment: @msh210 I suppose you are right that it could have been argued that even eating the animals would qualify as destroying them and killing them. Incidentally, if I understand [this comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87748/why-was-shaul-punished-for-not-killing-the-amaleiki-animals?noredirect=1#comment281625_87748) correctly, the OP assumes that only offering them as olot would qualify as destroying them.

Comment: 15:9 is very clear - he had pity on them, and did not intend on destroying them.  Therefore, he was punished.  (This question is based on Shaul's response in 15:15.)

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the end of the world if he would kill them by offering them rather than just throwing them out?

He delayed though - it may possibly have been fine if they were sacrificed immediately (I have to look into this), but that is all theoretical; by the time Shmuel arrives, after Shaul considers the job done, the animals are *still* alive. 
And since he delayed this, he was going against Hashem's command.

Answer (score 0):

The Gemara [Avoda Zara](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.24b.2) (24b) says:

> ת"ש (שמואל א טו, טו) ויאמר שאול מעמלקי הביאום אשר חמל העם על מיטב הצאן והבקר (המשנים והכרים ועל כל הצאן) למען זבוח לה' אלהיך מאי מיטב דמי מיטב
>
> The Gemara further states: Come and hear another objection from a verse: “And Saul said: They have brought them from the Amalekites; for the people spared the best of the flock and of the herd, to sacrifice unto the Lord your God” (I Samuel 15:15). The verse states explicitly that the Israelites intended to sacrifice animals previously owned by gentiles. The Gemara explains: What is the meaning of the phrase: “The best”? This is referring to the monetary value of the best livestock. The intention was not to sacrifice the animals themselves, but to sell them and use the proceeds of the sale to purchase other animals to sacrifice as offerings.

So the Amaleiki animals were to be sold, and other animals where to be bought with the value.